# Access to inner attribute with XMLSerializer

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to serialize XML file by using the XmlSerializer class. 
Xml Structure looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Datatable xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Assets>
    <A_elements>
      <A_el ID="1">
        <Fields>
          <Field Hint="First field">
             <Title> A_field </Title>
             <Value> 111 </Value>
          </Field>
          <Field Hint="Second field">
             <Title> B_field </Title>
             <Value> 222 </Value>
          </Field>
          .....
          .....
        </Fields>
      </A_el>
    </A_elements>
  </Assets>
</Datatable>
```

How can I access Field values when I specify  [XmlElement("")]?

For example, I want my C# object loaded from this xml be readable as:
`LoadedObject.Assets.A_elements[0].A_field`

and the output for the code above should be "111"

I am trying to solve this probem this way:

```
[XmlRoot("Assets"), Serializable]
    public class Assets
    {
        [XmlElement("A_elements")]
        public Actors actors { get; set; }
    }

public class A_elements
{
    [XmlElement("A_elements")]
    public List<A_el> A_elList { get; set; }
}


public class A_el
{
    [XmlAttribute("ID")]
    public int id { get; set; }
    [------??????------]
    public string A_field { get; set; }
}
```

Fields don't have any unique identifiers and there are lots of fields in all elements. I would really appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Field[] Fields member in your A_el class and a corresponding Field class that has Hint, Title and Value members.

```
public class A_el
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute("ID")]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArray(ElementName = "Fields")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItem("Field", typeof(Field))]
    public Field[] Fields { get; set; }

    private string[] _A_elements;
    private string[] A_elements
    {
        get
        {
            if(null == _A_elements)
            {
                _A_elements = (from field in Fields select field.Value).ToArray();
            }
            return _A_elements;
        }
    }
}

[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class Field
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string Hint { get; set; }
}
```

A handy tip: When you want to construct C# objects from serialisation, add a cs file to your project and open it.  Copy the XML you want to serialize, place the cursor in your cs file and instead of pasting, select Paste Special from the EDIT menu.  It will give you an option to 'Paste XML as classes'.

Comment: I created the Field class as partial, because I would expect the behaviour of the class to be implemented in a separate Field.cs file, assuming that all the XML serialisation stuff is gathered together in a single 'xmlserialization.cs' file, or similar.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! 
In this case, how could I access to value of A_field from loaded object? 
Like I said I want to read loaded object as
`LoadedObject.Assets.A_elements[0].A_field`
and get the output "111"

With your way of solving it I will have to do it like 
`LoadedObject.Assets.A_elements[0].Field[0].Value`

Comment: Editted my answer.  It's still not quite what you want, but might give you an idea.  :-)

Comment: Thank you :) I think, I got it. 
I don't have enough reputation to upvote your answer. I hope you will find sufficient my sincere gratitude from the depths of the heart :D

Comment: I'm not completely sure you can do what you're asking for syntactically.  In the code above you could change the _A_element to be a Dictionary and in the A_element get construct the Dictionary from the field.Title and field.Value strings then access it using LoadedObject.Assests.A_elements[0].A_elements["A_Field"], but I'm not sure that's any better.  Alternatively, you'd just have to add an A_Field property to A_el, that returned Fields["A_Field"].Value in its getter.

Comment: @Mad You're welcome.  Hope you find what you need and have fun getting there.